# Jenkins' Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin: Trigger on all branches except master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'd like to have [the Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) to trigger on all branches but master. Is this possible? Using the "Optional filter" I can create a regular expression that says basically to trigger on all branches that matches a given name, but I haven't found a way to trigger on all matches but "master".

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you mark all your branches except the master branches with a particular regex? And then you call that particular tag. I assume you already looked on here: 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for your input. I ended up solving this in another way. See the answer I posed. But I'd gone for your suggestions if I hadn't already implemented the other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something slightly different. I made my the Generic Webhook Plugin in my current job trigger only on push'es to master. I then created another job that uses Git Parameter plugin to list all available branches, so that I manually can run a build on a non-master branch.